# Parsing live source code from website

Tags: c#, javascript

I am trying to parse the song from Grooveshark but I don't know how to access JavaScript updated source code. When I use URL I get original source and not live source updated by JavaScript, which means I cannot access some new ID data.

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='now-playing-metadata']/a");
text = node.FirstChild.InnerText.Trim();
```

I am using HTML Agility library to parse website.

Comment: The [terms of service at grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/#!/legal/terms) specify `You agree not to display or use any EMG intellectual property without EMG's prior permission.` - you have sought their permission, right?

Comment: Grooveshark has an API: http://developers.grooveshark.com/tuts/tinysong

Comment: You would have to find some way of running the javascript once you download the source of the page. However, because you are running a "copy" of the page, and not the actual, the script may be broken, or will look for connections that don't exist. Use that API that @Blender mentioned.

Comment: I saw they have api, but what I need is to show what song is someone currently playing in Grooveshark playlist.. May it be anonymous user or logged in, that doesn't matter. I requested API key but as I was checking the methods they offer with their API, I don't know if that is possible for anonymous user. I have read their terms of service, I am just learning to parse live source for my personal project..

Comment: The [dev doc page](http://developers.grooveshark.com/docs/) says `If you are looking to interact with a user's current song or session, then you have to use the Grooveshark.com JS API.` Try looking at [this api](http://developers.grooveshark.com/docs/js_api/#getCurrentSongStatus).

Comment: The "live source" you refer to is the Document Object Model (DOM). This is the driving force behind a browser; you'll at least need a decent HTML parser and JS interpreter for this. Html Agility Pack is basically just an elaborate string parser; it ignores (or certainly doesn't execute) the JavaScript on the page. What you want to do can easily be done from a browser plugin or user script; through a standalone application this is much harder as you'll have to emulate a browser engine.

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out, the problem is Html Agility Pack just uses Http client to download the URL as a string. In your case you need to execute the downloaded content in a Javascript engine with a DOM. I would suggest a headless browser client like phantom.js, there are C# drivers available.

With phantom.js you can do something like:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.grooveshark.com/");
var node = driver.FindElement(By.Id("now-playing-metadata"));
```